# Choose the max value out of options per row in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery that looks like that:

```
ID  OPTIONS   A   B   C   D   E
1  ['A','C'] 0.1 0.9 0.3 0.7  0
2  ['B','C'] 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.6  1
3  ['A','D'] 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.1  0.6
```

I want to get the maximum option per row out of 'OPTIONS', example:

```
ID  OPTIONS   A   B   C   D   E    MAX_OPTION
1  ['A','C'] 0.1 0.9 0.3 0.7  0.      C
2  ['B','C'] 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.6  1       C
3  ['A','D'] 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.1  0.6     A
```

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  GREATEST(
    IF('A' IN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(bonus_options, r'"([^"]+)"')), A, -99999), 
    IF('B' IN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(bonus_options, r'"([^"]+)"')), B, -99999), 
    IF('C' IN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(bonus_options, r'"([^"]+)"')), C, -99999), 
    IF('D' IN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(bonus_options, r'"([^"]+)"')), D, -99999), 
    IF('E' IN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(bonus_options, r'"([^"]+)"')), E, -99999),
  ) AS MAX_OPTION
FROM 
  `TABLE`
```

But I get NULL in MAX_OPTION.
What can I do?

Comment: in your example, the line with ID 3 should have max_option A, or do I understand wrongly what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @ruud yes that was my mistake, i fixed it.

Comment: have you tried replacing the NULL's in your query by 1,2,3,4,5 to see if it is THAT null that you get back?

Comment: [greatest](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) _Returns the greatest value among X1,...,XN. If any argument is NULL, returns NULL._

Comment: Thanks, but I dont get the name of the col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
      * EXCEPT (MAX_OPTION), 
      CASE
        WHEN A=MAX_OPTION THEN 'A'
        WHEN B=MAX_OPTION THEN 'B'
        WHEN C=MAX_OPTION THEN 'C'
        WHEN D=MAX_OPTION THEN 'D'
        WHEN E=MAX_OPTION THEN 'E'
      END as MAX_OPTION
    FROM (
    SELECT 
      ID,
      GREATEST(
        IF('A' IN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(bonus_options, r'"([^"]+)"')), A, -99999), 
        IF('B' IN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(bonus_options, r'"([^"]+)"')), B, -99999), 
        IF('C' IN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(bonus_options, r'"([^"]+)"')), C, -99999), 
        IF('D' IN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(bonus_options, r'"([^"]+)"')), D, -99999), 
        IF('E' IN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(bonus_options, r'"([^"]+)"')), E, -99999),
      ) AS MAX_OPTION
    FROM 
      `TABLE`)
```